# Set environment variables in an AWS instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, terraform

I create an **AMI in EC2 with terraform** with this resource:

```
resource "aws_instance" "devops-demo" {
  ami           = "jnkdjsndjsnfsdj"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name      = "demo-devops"
  user_data     = "${file("ops_setup.sh")}"
}
```

The user data executes a **shell script** that install Java JRE:

```
  sudo yum remove java-1.7.0-openjdk -y
  sudo wget -O /opt/server-jre-8u172-linux-x64.tar.gz --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u172-b11/a58eab1ec242421181065cdc37240b08/server-jre-8u172-linux-x64.tar.gz"
  sudo tar xzf /opt/server-jre-8u172-linux-x64.tar.gz
  export JAVA_HOME=/jdk1.8.0_172
  export JRE_HOME=/jdk1.8.0_171/jre
  export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

But none of the environment variables work. However, if I connect by ssh to the instance and I execute the export command, it works fine.

Is there any way to define the environment variables with terraform?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using the export command only sets those variables for the current shell and all processes that start from that shell. It is not a persistent setting. Anything you wish to make permanent should be set in `/etc/environment`.

For example in userdata:

```
echo "JAVA_HOME=/jdk1.8.0_172" >> /etc/environment
```

This would add the `JAVA_HOME=/jdk1.8.0_172` line to that file. Note, you should not use `export` inside that file.

The `PATH` variable is likely already defined in the `/etc/environment` file and you'll need to overwrite that appropriately if you are going to append additional paths to it.

There is really great details on setting environment variables available in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/58828/834411).

Answer (score 4):

If you are using one of the Amazon Linux 2 AMIs, then `/etc/environment` will not work for you. However, you can add the environment variables to a new file at `/etc/profile.d/` and this will work. Something like this would go in your `user_data`:

```sh
echo "JAVA_HOME=/jdk1.8.0_172" | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/java_setup.sh
echo "JRE_HOME=/jdk1.8.0_171/jre" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/java_setup.sh
echo "PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/java_setup.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

To set environment variables in an AWS instance, you can do the following:

1. Connect to your instance using SSH.
2. Navigate to the directory where you want to set the environment variable.
3. Open the .bashrc file using the command 'nano ~/.bashrc'.
4. Scroll to the bottom of the file and add the environment variable in the following format: 'export VARIABLE_NAME=value' (replace VARIABLE_NAME and value with your desired values).
5. Save the file by pressing 'CTRL + X', then 'Y', and finally 'Enter'.
6. To apply the changes, run the command 'source ~/.bashrc' in your terminal.

That's it! Your environment variable should now be set and ready to use.