# Best way to set environment variables on EC2 using Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I am creating EC2 instances using Terraform. There are a number of environment variables that I would like to set on these instances, with values determined by other parts of my Terraform script. For example, I would like to pass a database connection string to a managed RDS instance.

One method of doing this (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50668528/1256041)) is to use a Terraform template to generate a user-data script that writes the variables to `/etc/environment`. However, this seems like something so common that it would have a recommended approach. I would also like to avoid dealing with AWS specific mechanisms, if possible.

What is the recommended way of setting environment variables on machines created by Terraform?

Comment: you could have a script in the user script to inject them in the server.

Answer (score 0):

A good way would be to generate a script which has all your environment variable then source at startup.
Also , above answer should help you and I dont see any AWS specific stuff in the answer.